# Load AngularJS controller in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I have a jQuery UI dialog, and in this pop up I have a dynamic `<select>` with angular and Ajax request. My dialog shows up if I click on a button, but AngularJS script is played even if dialog isn't visible.

I stopped my script with a condition : `if($("#MyDialog).dialog("isOpen") ===true)"`

And it works, but I don't know how to "reload" my Angular Controller to load select input when my dialog is displayed...

I tried this : `MyController(angular.element($('div[ng-controller="MyController"]')).scope(), angular.element($('div[ng-controller="MyController"]')).http);`

but it doesn't works... Any idea ?

Code of my controller :

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    if ($("#myDialog").dialog("isOpen") === true) {
        $http.
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.select = data;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("error !");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an anti pattern in angular.js -> `$("#myDialog")` , This code should probably live inside a directive. please provide a plunker

Comment: There's no point to use AngularJS if you aren't trying to enforce the practices they strive to enforce. You shouldn't access DOM elements in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing whether the modal is open try placing a ng-click on the open modal button or link.

```
<button ng-click="loadSelectData()">Open Modal</button>

<script>
    app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loadSelectData = function () {
            // fetch your select data
            // also you can check if you already have the data before going to server
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: I will use a jquery ui dialog controlled by angular, so my select box will be loaded on a ng-click like you did. Thanks !